# Usefulness of tag [encoding] - description change

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I think the tag [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding) has too wide meaning to be useful. For example the video encoding and the character encoding have very little in common, yet people use the same tag for them. There are specialized versions listing on the Wiki ([video-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-encoding) and [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding)), unfortunately people don't bother to use them. There is a way too many questions that should be retagged.

I think it would be useful to add warning to not use the base tag but a specialized version. There is something like that with [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft).

Comment: There are people who are knowledge about in encoding, so yes it is useful.

Comment: @ShaunLoftin you mean that there are people who are knowledgeable about encoding *something*, right? Because encoding by itself is a very loose concept; what are we encoding?

Comment: The tag is pretty clear :
> Encoding is a set of predefined rules to reversibly transform a piece of information in a certain representation into a completely different representation.
If I where to do some design and had a hard time representing a complexe concept as a structure that would be the tag to use. The thing is most poeple us this tag in a very different way that is related but would fit more specific tags hence polluting this very 'theoretical' tag. For me `[encoding]` would be like `[theoretical-data-structure]`

Comment: @Amxx It would be better to add the [theoretical-encoding] tag.

Comment: @Amxx for you, may be; for the thousands questions that have that tag, not so much. Tip: the highest count has it utf-8 + encoding combination.

Comment: Just saying my opinion is the theory of this tag is good, but it's not used as it should ...

Answer (score 2):

There are many tags like that, for example [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [ms-office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office) and etc.
I think this tags are useful, Because:

- When OP is not aware of other tags or
- When OP is not aware of importance of tags or
- When OP never takes any time for finding better tags or
- When OP select the first tag as recommended in their pop up list -ordered by count of uses- or
- When OP is in a hurry or some other reasons like these,

> I think we need editors!

You can be an editor and edit that question and its tags and I suggest you to do these:

- Edit tag wiki and its pop up text to aware users about when they should use it.
- Edit questions of that tag with commenting about why you remove that tag.
- Some times you also need to suggest a synonym.